# How can I deploy Lightning components from sandbox to production

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am replicating Visualforce pages in Lightning. Same Visualforce page functionality I used in Lightning.

1. My question is how can I move lightning components from sandbox to production?
2. Whether I have to write one more test class for the Lightning component? Or can I use same visualforce page test class here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can deploy your lightning components using Change sets or any other Metadata based deployment options as you usually do for your visualforce pages
2. If you are re-using the same Apex classes in the backend, your existing test classes should cover them. but in the process of supporting the lightning components, if you made any changes to your Apex classes, then you need to update the test classes to handle the new changes.

Comment: If you're using change-sets select the component type = "Aura Component Bundle"